# リンク不正: 「UTC」のリンクが英語版Wikipediaになっている

Tags: バグ, 完了, ハイパーリンク

以下のようなバッジの説明に「UTC」という単語が入っているが、この単語にはWikipediaへのリンクが張られている。
ただ、英語版のWikipediaへのリンクになっているので、日本語版のWikipediaへのリンクに修正したほうが良い。
(誤)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time
(正)
http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%94%E5%AE%9A%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E6%99%82

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本件、リンクが修正されている事を確認しました。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges